# JSON data used a variable in URL (PHP Curl)

Tags: php, json, curl, put

Can i pass a JSON data as a variable to a url for a PHP put request?

```
 $data = array("trackingNumber" => "940550369930025071935", "fulfillmentStatus" => "SHIPPED", "orderNumber" => "0137077");                                                                    

 $data_string = json_encode($data);


    $url = 'https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/{STOREID}/orders/'.$data['orderNumber']'?token={TOKEN}';
```

As you can see orderNumber is needed for the url.

Error: unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: You missed a period: `/orders/'.$data['orderNumber']./*here*/'?token=`

Comment: Perfect - Thank you.